# Scala Filter Only Digits

Tags: scala, apache-spark

If I have this scala output code:

```
(1,ab)
(2,fd)
(4, df)
(a,1)
(b,3)
(c,4)
(d,6)
```

And I want to delete all of the tuples which have a digit in the first slot in the tuple such as the first three here: `(1,ab) (2,fd) (4, df)`.

For some reason the code I have here is not correctly filtering the those tuples:

```
val temp = t.countByValue().filter(_._1 != Int).print()
```

The `countByValue()` function returns a tuple of `(value (in my case a string like (a,b,c,), count of the times the string occurs)`.

Comment: what is the type `countByValue` returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might solve your problem

```
t.countByValue().filter(tupleOfCount=>Try(tupleOfCount._1.toInt).toOption.isEmpty).print()
```

Use of isInstanceOf should be the last resort as @sergey said , so this code must solve the issue or else the pattern matching would be a good option too.

Answer (score -1):

```
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  var newlist = List((1 -> "a"), ("b") -> 2, ("c" -> 3))
  newlist.foreach(tuple => if (tuple._1.isInstanceOf[Int]) {
     println(tuple._1 + "-" + tuple._2)
  })
 }
```

Hope it can help. BTW (1,ab) if your ab is a string you need "ab".